# Excel formula calculating differently based on location within worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a simple formula that sums 2 cells, lets say C4 and C5 (that have complicated formulas in them but they have static results). When that formula is positioned in cell B3 it generates a certain result, lets say 56. But when I type the same formula into cell D7 it generates a different result, lets say 64.

Upon further testing I found that the issue has to do with where the formula is entered within the excel worksheet. If I enter the formula in any cell above row 4 (any column) it generates a result of 56. I can even drag that cell from one position to another and generates that result in that area of the worksheet. When I enter that formula anywhere within row 4 (any column) it generates a new result, lets say 59. I can even drag a cell with the formula in it from a row above row 4, onto a cell in row 4, and the result will change to 59. The same thing happens to all cells below row 4 (any column) so that the formula entered below row 4 will generate 64 and when I drag a cell with the formula in it from either above or on row 4 the result changes to 64.

It is important to note that the only correct calculation is the one that generates on row 4. The other results are mathematically incorrect anywhere above or below row 4.

Lastly, the more complicated formula that is located in C4 (on row 4) is actually calculating incorrectly. I can get it to become the correct result by clicking the cell (C4) and then clicking into the formula bar and hitting F9. When I do that the formula is replaced by the correct result as a value (a different value than what is shown when the formula is entered in the cell.

I have no idea what could be occurring, I have iterative calculation on and have played with it anywhere from 10-1,000. I have automatic calculation on from the Formulas tab (I have tried turning it off and back on and it doesnt make a difference). I even just took it a step further and input =C4 into a cell above and below row 4 and they display different numbers that are not the value in cell C4.

Comment: Are your formulas set for xlR1C1 input or xlA1?

Comment: Please [Edit] your post and add some sample data along with the Formula you have tried so far  will help us to fix the issue!!